# How does the function composition (.) operator work with multiple compositions?

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I know that the dot (.) operator is defined to take three arguments(two functions and a value of type "a"), and works by the application of applying the argument to the function on the right, and the function on the left is applied to the output of the application of the left side, like follows:

```
-- Associativity: infixr 9
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(f . g) x = f(g x)
-- Or in another format
f . g = \x -> f(g x)
```

Now, that's what's confusing with more than one application with the dot operator in a function composition, consider this:

With an infix operator like (+), it takes two arguments of types within the "Num" class.

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a

-- An application would look like this:
> 4 + 3
7

-- With more applications composed with (+)
> 4 + 3 + 2
9

-- Which is fine, since the last application
-- still takes two arguments of the legitimate types,
-- which is a value of type within "Num" class, as follows
> (4 + 3) + 2
-- 7 + 2
9
```

But with the dot operator, as follows. The last function composition with the dot operator should instead take the output of the application "reverse . take 3 $ map (*2) [1..]", which is "[6,4,2]" of the previous function composition.

If that's what I said, the dot operator takes a value instead of a function and a value on the right side, how is it supposed to work?

```
> replicate 4 . reverse . take 3 $ map (*2) [1..]
[[6,4,2],[6,4,2],[6,4,2],[6,4,2]]
```

Isn't it supposed to be like follows for its middle step?

```
-- And it's not going to work, since the dot operator
-- is defined to take three arguments of two functions
-- "(b -> c)" and "(a -> b)"
-- and the value of type "a"
replicate 4 . [6,4,2]
```

Since an application of dot operator takes three arguments and then returns a result of a value of type "a".

So the part "reverse . take 3 $ map (*2) [1..]" on the left side should be evaluated to "[6,4,2]"

Why is it not?

Comment: When you say "`.` takes three arguments" you are correct, but note that in Haskell you can always pass fewer arguments, and obtain a function of the remaining arguments. You can pretend that the operator is defined as a binary function `f . g = (\x -> f (g x))`. When using it in infix form as `f . g . h . i . j . k` it's best to think of `.` as a binary operator, like `+`.

Comment: Every function in Haskell takes exactly one argument. For example, `(.) :: (a->b) -> (b->c) -> a -> c` looks like taking 3 arguments, but if you put the omitted parentheses back, you get `(.) :: (a->b) -> ((b->c) -> (a->c))`. It's the exact same type but expressed more clearly. Gets a function and returns a function. (And that one also gets a function and returns a function). If you are lost in the many arguments of some complicated function, stop and think in these terms.

Comment: I think you’re misreading the operator precedence here. `(.)` is `infixr 9` while `($)` is `infixr 0`. You can find this from the `:info` command in GHCi, the Hackage docs, or the Haskell Report. So `f . g . h $ x` is `(f . (g . h)) $ x`, not `f . ((g . h) $ x)` as you wrote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting confused by currification (more on this later). You can think of `(.)` as taking two arguments (as `(+)` does).

```hs
-- Associativity: infixr 9
--                             |- this parens. aren't necessary, but It helps to make them explicit
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
--     |- input 1  |- input 2  |- result function
```

Now, because `(.)` it is right assoc the two lines of code below are equivalent

```
replicate 4 . reverse . take 3   
replicate 4 . (reverse . take 3) -- by right assoc. property
```

in order to make this more explicit let me rewrite the code above

```hs
-- original
doSomething = replicate 4 . reverse . take 3 $ map (*2) [1..]

-- original with explicit parenthesis
doSomething = ( replicate 4 . (reverse . take 3) ) (map (*2) [1..])
              |               |- right assoc  -| | |              |
              |                                  | |              |
              |- these four are the result of deleting $ symbol  -|

-- factor out each parenthesis. Types are monomorphise for clarity.
doSomething = (replicateFour . takeThreeAndReverse) evenNumbers 
  where replicateFour       = replicate 4      -- :: [Int] -> [[Int]]  
        takeThreeAndReverse = reverse . take 3 -- :: [Int] -> [Int]
        evenNumbers         = map (*2) [1..]   -- :: [Int]
```

Now, the technique we are applying here is called currying. Which can be summarize as "a function which takes two arguments can be re-written as a function taking one argument and returning another function taking one argument."

Some python code for the sake of understanding

```py
# The following two are equivalent functions. 
def add(x, y):
  return x + y

def add_curry(x):
  def inner(y):
    return x + y
  return inner # we return a function not a value

add(3, 4) == add(3)(4) # notice double function call in RHS
```

Now, all haskell functions are curried, this actually make a lot of sense on a functional language because if simplifies a lot composition and makes the language more ergonomic in most situations (altough, this is an opinion and someothers may ague differently)

Currying can be a headache in the beginning but eventually It fells pretty natural. The best way to overcome it is by doing a lot of exercises and trying to use a lot of partial application

Comment: Do you mean that a function composition in an application which the composition is applied the argument "x" like "f . k . g . z $ x", where the part "f . k . g . z" is already first an application in terms of itself which the precedence is as "(f . (k . (g . z)))" and returns a function that takes the argument "x"? Not like the part "(g . z)" in "f . k . g . z" is applied to the argument "x" first, since the precedence of applications of the dot operator is 9, where of the dollar operator is 0? Do I finally correctly understand it? To be honest, I'd argue that the demo above is fairly unclear

Comment: Honestly, this is very very confusing, the most importance isn't currying at all, since its concept is easy to understand and introduced in the very beginning of most haskell guides & books. It's about which part evaluates first in an application of a function composition, where the part "f . k . g . z" is evaluated first and returns a function that and then is applied to the argument "x". Not the first composition "(g . z) in "(f . (k . (g . z)))" that takes the argument "x" like "(g . z) x -> c" and then "(f . (k . c))" and so forth. Any way, thanks for all of you who have helped me! Thanks!

Comment: I was confused by the part "x" of the defnition of the dot operator "(f . g) x = f (g x)", where it looks like an immediate application with the argument "x". Even in multiple compositions like "f . k . g . z $ x", I still thought the part (g . z $ x) would be first evaluated and so forth. But it was wrong, since applications of the dot operator have precedence of 9, which is higher than the dollar operator of 0. So, instead, the composions in an application will first be evaluated and then returns a function that finally takes the argument "x".

Comment: You said I'm confused by currification, but not exactly. Strictly speaking, it's by lazy evaluation(which relays on currying) and precedence "in process" of an application of a function composition. I never thought lazy evaluation can be some kind of "nested" by another function that lacks arguments taking a function that also lacks arguments and so forth like in function composition, where the lacking arguments can keep lacking till they're finally given without error

Comment: @Akari. Ok you were confused by precedence: `.` is applied before `$`. Just a comment: currification has absolutely nothing to do with lazy evaluation, you can write your haskell code completely un-curried and still will be lazily evaluated. If you are learning haskell,  I'd suggest you completely forget about lazy evaluation (I know  every book introduce it, but It is just useless when learning the language).

Comment: Sorry, it appears I was also wrong about partial application being based on lazy application, and also thought lazy application being based on currying.. I misunderstood so many concepts to ask the question :( Sorry, I need to go study more

Comment: @Akari, Don't worry. That's what SO is for, isn't it?. Eventually Haskell will make sense, I promise hahahaha

Answer (score 1):

In short, in an application of a multi function composition said "(t . z . f. g)" with an argument said "x", each single composition of the function composition will be evaluated first from right to left, by the precedence of "infixr 9" of the dot operator, before getting applied to the argument "x", since the composition and the given argument are separated by the dollar operator which is defined with the precedence of "infixr 0".

```
The composition: (t . z . f . g)

Each function's type:
t :: (d -> e)
z :: (c -> d)
f :: (b -> c)
g :: (a -> b)

Actual type: 
(t . z . f . g) :: a -> e
```

Now, because of currying, the dot operator is defined to take three arguments of two functions and a value, said "(b -> c)", "(a -> b)" and "a", if the dot operator only takes these two functions, it will then return a function "(a -> c)" as the right operand of the next dot operator, and so on in a multi function composition.

```
Type in process for each composition with the dot operator:
(d -> e) . (c -> d) . (b -> c) . (a -> b) $ a
((d -> e) . (c -> d) . (b -> c) . (a -> b)) a
((d -> e) . (c -> d) . (a -> c)) a
((d -> e) . (a -> d)) a
(a -> e) a
```

In a real case:

```
> :t (replicate 3 . reverse . take 3 . map (*3))
(replicate 3 . reverse . take 3 . map (*3))
  :: Num a => [a] -> [[a]]
> replicate 3 . reverse . take 3 . map (*3) $ [1..]
[[9,6,3],[9,6,3],[9,6,3]]
```

It works as expected :)

Thanks @lsmor for the detailed & inspirational answer. This post is my way of understanding, not about which is better. Thanks a lot!